# Null Models with default arguments need to be instantiated as such

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, model-binding, action-filter

I have the following asp.net WebApi2 route using .NET 4.6 that illustrates the problem I am having:

```
[Route("books/{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public JsonResponse GetBooks(string id, [FromUri]DescriptorModel model)
```

With the following model:

```
public class DescriptorModel
{
    public bool Fiction { get; set; } = false;

    // other properties with default arguments here
}
```

I am trying to allow Fiction property to be set to a default value (if not specified during the get request).

When I specify the Fiction property explicitly it works correctly:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://127.0.0.1:11000/api/v1/books/516.375/?Fiction=false'
```

However, when doing the following test (omitting the property with the default argument):

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://127.0.0.1:11000/api/v1/books/516.375'
```

The value of "model" is bound as null which is not what I am looking for. My question is how to simply allow models defined with default values to be instantiated as such during/after the model binding process but prior to the controller's "GetBooks" action method being called.

NOTE. the reason I use models with GET requests is that documenting in swagger is much easier as then my GET/POST actions can reuse the same models in many case via inheritance.

Comment: just try to use [FromQuery] instead of [FromUri] and nothing else.it will work

Comment: @masoud isn’t [FromQuery] from asp.net core? I’m using asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out how to do this via model-binding but I was able to use Action Filters to accomplish the same thing.

Here's the code I used (note it only supports one null model per action but this could easily be fixed if needed):

```
public class NullModelActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext context)
    {
        object value = null;
        string modelName = string.Empty;

        // are there any null models?
        if (context.ActionArguments.ContainsValue(null))
        {
            // Yes => iterate over all arguments to find them.
            foreach (var arg in context.ActionArguments)
            {
                // Is the argument null?
                if (arg.Value == null)
                {
                    // Search the parameter bindings to find the matching argument....
                    foreach (var parameter in context.ActionDescriptor.ActionBinding.ParameterBindings)
                    {
                        //  Did we find a match?
                        if (parameter.Descriptor.ParameterName == arg.Key)
                        {
                            // Yes => Does the type have the 'Default' attribute?
                            var type = parameter.Descriptor.ParameterType;
                            if (type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DefaultAttribute), false).Length > 0)
                            {
                                // Yes => need to instantiate it
                                modelName = arg.Key;
                                var constructor = parameter.Descriptor.ParameterType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
                                value = constructor.Invoke(null);

                                // update the model state
                                context.ModelState.Add(arg.Key, new ModelState { Value = new ValueProviderResult(value, value.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // update the action arguments
            context.ActionArguments[modelName] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I created a DefaultAttribute class like so:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DefaultAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

I then added that attribute to my descriptor class:

```
[Default]
public class DescriptorModel
{
    public bool Fiction { get; set; } = false;

    // other properties with default arguments here
}
```

And finally registered the action filter in

```
public void Configure(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    // lots of configuration here omitted
    config.Filters.Add(new NullModelActionFilter());
    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

I definitely consider this a hack (I think I really should be doing this via model binding) but it accomplishes what I needed to do with the constraints that I was given of ASP.NET (not Core) / WebApi2 / .NET Framework so hopefully some else will benefit from this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using id as FromUri, the only way you can use a model with get is to use url with a query string

```
[Route("~/GetBooks/{id?}")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetBooks(string id, [FromQuery] DescriptorModel model)
```

in this case you url should be

```
'http://127.0.0.1:11000/api/v1/books/?Name=name&&fiction=true'

//or if fiction==false just
'http://127.0.0.1:11000/api/v1/books/?Name=name'

//or if want to use id
'http://127.0.0.1:11000/api/v1/books/123/?Name=name&&fiction=true'
```

using model  your way will be working only  with [FromForm] or [FromBody].
To use it as MVC recomends try this

```
[Route("books/{id}/{param1}/{param2}/{fiction?}")]
[HttpGet]
public JsonResponse GetBooks(string id, string param1, string param2, bool fiction)
```

By the way, you don't need to make bool false as default since it is false by default any way

if you want to use ID and  DescriptorModel from uri you can do this only if you add Id to DescriptorModel too

```
[Route("books/{id}/{param1}/{param2}/{fiction?}")]
[HttpGet]
public JsonResponse GetBooks(DescriptorModel model)
```

UPDATE

If your mvc doesnt support [FromQuery], you can use RequestQuery inside of action like this

```
 var value= context.Request.Query["value"];
```

but is better to update to MVC 6.

Comment: You can use models for Get requests with the [FromUri] attribute. It's convenient so that get/posts can use the same model and makes documenting in swagger easier.

Comment: You can't the way you trying to do it. pls make it working and let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe your answer is only appropriate for asp.net core. There is no [FromQuery] attribute that I am aware of in regular asp.net.

Comment: MVC 6 supports [FromQuery]. What version are you using?

Comment: The nuget version is 5.2.7 (due to .NET 4.6).

Comment: Documentation is found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/